# I have <`0`> with Vim-Latex, what is it?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, latex, keyboard-shortcuts

Sorry to bother you guys with this silly question.

I have Vim-Latex suite with my spf13-Vim. However, when I was writing my paper, I some times got auto-complete like:

```
\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \includegrahics[width=3]{<`2`>}
   \caption{<`3`>}
   \label{}
\end{figure}
```

I have checked the Vim-Latex manual, however, it just mentioned `<C-j>` jump. I really confused with this <`#`> thing, is it a jump place?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I get rid of spf13. It's totally a black box.
However, it's a good Bundle list and template for reference.
The pattern I mentioned in the question comes from neocomplete.
To jump to each numbered block, just press:
< C-k >.